# jQuery not executing because of asp:Panel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, panel

I am using the jQuery plug in contentcarousel.  It is a good plugin and all but I need the ability to dynamically create a certain number divs according to the user.

To achieve this I am using an `<asp:panel>` and then running a Literal & foreach in C# to populate the panel.  The problem comes in when the `<asp:panel>` is used.

It seems as if the jQuery plugin can only work if the divs occur in a certain order.

ie.

```html
<div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
<div class="cawrapper">
<div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
<div class="ca-item-main">
```

When the panel is used, then the order becomes

```html
<div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
<div class="cawrapper">
<div id="panelinfo">
<div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
<div class="ca-item-main">
```

And the plugin stops working.  At least I am assuming so due to the fact that the arrows dont show up, none of the buttons work, etc.

Does anyone know if there is a way around this? Maybe a way to "hide" the div that the panel becomes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a control that acts like a `Panel` in server side code, but instead of being rendered as a `div` just plops all of whatever would have been inside of it without adding anything "extra".  That's pretty much the definition of an `asp:Placeholder`.  Just use that instead of a `Panel`.

Comment: Thank you! I always thought placeholder was a bit different but it seems exactly what I need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your JQuery code into window.load.  I'm assuming you have your jquery in document.ready which will fire the second the dom is ready.

```
$(window).load(function(){/*Your code*/}
```